# Rust eqivalent to scipy truncnorm

Tags: rust, random

Trying to generate a random number between 0-200 in Rust using normal distribution. Is this something that I have to implement myself or is there a crate like `scipy` for rust that has `truncnorm`?

I've tried using some combination of `.gen_range()` and `.sample(Standard)` but can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random float from Standard Normal distribution and multiply by another float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64724454/generate-random-float-from-standard-normal-distribution-and-multiply-by-another)

Comment: Or better, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72115301/is-it-possible-to-sample-from-user-defined-distribution-in-rust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of [`truncnorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html) doesn't seem to be among the [currently implmented distributions](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand_distr/index.html) in the `rand_distr` crate.

But you can easily implement it yourself: sample from the [`Normal`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand_distr/struct.Normal.html) distribution, and if the sample is outside the desired range, just try again.

As long as the range is at least a few standard deviations, the extra overhead from discarded samples should be negligible. If this doesn't cover your use case, take a look at [the scipy source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L8655-L8830) to see how it's done.

Comment: Okay, yeah I thought this might be the case, just thought I would double check to make sure I didn't miss anything obvious. Thanks!